# Add 1 extra data point to neural network without retraining whole model

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I have forecasting project where I am trying to predict the next value in a time series. I am using Python 2.7.x, Keras 2.0.4 and Theano 0.9.0.

I want to evaluate the model by predicting the value of each of the last X points of the time series given the first X-1 points, and then averaging the prediction error.

Lets say I have 10 data points in total and my X=4. The first model would be constructed on knowledge from the first 6 data points and used to predict the 7th point. 
I would then like to add the 7th point to the model to predict the 8th point, but without having to completely retrain the model.

In the demo code below I use the numbers 1 to 10 as time series data

```
import math
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# The time series points in this demo are the numbers 1 to 10
x_train = [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)]
y_train = [3, 4, 5, 6]

x_test = [(5, 6)]
y_test = [7]

# Create NN model and train on original training data set
nn = Sequential()
nn.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))  # Input/Hidden layer
nn.add(Dense(1))  # Output layer
nn.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
nn.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=2)
prediction = nn.predict(numpy.array(x_test))[0][0]
abs_error = math.fabs(prediction - y_test)

# TODO How do I fit the model to the (x_test, y_test) data to improve the model without
# retraining from scratch ?
# Below is my best guess. If value of epoch is 1 then the model only 'sees' the new point
# once while it has seen the other points 100 times (#epochs above). But if I set it to
# 100 I fear the model will skew heavily towards the new point.
nn.fit(x_test, y_test, initial_epoch=100, epochs='1 OR 100 OR SomethingElseCompletely ?', batch_size=1)

# TODO Predict next_y based on next_x
```

Am I completely off base or is it possible to add an extra training point to a NN given the above scenario ?

Comment: Have you tested what happens when you use the two strategies you proposed? I would also test one, where you add the new datapoint to the old data and continue training and then compare all three with a complete retraining from scratch.

Comment: No, I have not tried any of the strategies. I was hoping for a 'do this since this is obviously better' answer. It will be really time consuming since I  need to perform network parameter optimization (# hidden nodes and # input nodes) and for each configuration I should probably run ~10 iterations to account for random weight initialization. This might result in ~500 iteration and I have not accounted for my X which is ~30. So my reason for asking is because I don't have time to perform theses tests. Sorry for not mentioning that.